# All these verses to say before havdala

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, havdalah

Before saying the blessings relevant to *havdala* on *motzei shabbos*, we (Ashkenazim) include a bunch of *p'sukim*:

- "הִנֵּה אֵל יְשׁוּעָתִי אֶבְטַח וְלֹא אֶפְחָד כִּי עָזִּי וְזִמְרָת יָהּ יְהוָה וַיְהִי לִי לִישׁוּעָה. וּשְׁאַבְתֶּם מַיִם בְּשָׂשׂוֹן מִמַּעַיְנֵי הַיְשׁוּעָה"  (Yeshayahu 12:2-3)
- "לַיהוָה הַיְשׁוּעָה עַל עַמְּךָ בִרְכָתֶךָ סֶּלָה" (Tehillim 3:9)
- "יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת עִמָּנוּ מִשְׂגָּב לָנוּ אֱלֹהֵי יַעֲקֹב סֶלָה" (Tehillim 46:12)
- "יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת אַשְׁרֵי אָדָם בֹּטֵחַ בָּךְ" (Tehillim 84:13)
- "יְהוָה הוֹשִׁיעָה הַמֶּלֶךְ יַעֲנֵנוּ בְיוֹם קָרְאֵנוּ" (Tehillim 20:10)
- "לַיְּהוּדִים הָיְתָה אוֹרָה וְשִׂמְחָה וְשָׂשֹׂן וִיקָר" (Esther 8:16) [Then we add "כן תהיה לנו"]
- "כּוֹס יְשׁוּעוֹת אֶשָּׂא וּבְשֵׁם יְהוָה אֶקְרָא" (Tehillim 116:13)

What is the history of these *p'sukim* prefacing the *b'rachos* of *havdala*, and what is their significance? Why these specific verses over any others?

Comment: The connection seems to be yeshua, but I don't know the connection to Havdala/Yetzias shabbos.

Comment: I bet its to save the souls from going back to gehenom. Also, the verses refer to various parts of the havdalah service itself. (or  and Kos)

Comment: The German minhag does not include bullets 4 and 5.

Comment: @JXG I have wondered if the reason for this is to specifically have 6 verses parallel to the 6 week days.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Rema on Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 296:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=142), which brings 3 (or maybe 4) of the verses (but in a different order), and says it is for a "Siman Tov", a good sign.

See [Dayan Raskin's Siddur (footnote 8)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=384) where he discusses the various sources for the different verses we say before the blessings.